# How to change Built In / exisiting ApplicationCommands Shortcut

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to change 'built-in' copy command shortcut to for example 'CTRL + Q' or 
add to existing EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize shortcut?

I know how to do it making command from scratch, but how to edit it for exisiting commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new `KeyGesture` to command's [`InputGetures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.inputgestures%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection

```cs
EditingCommands.IncreaseFontSize.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

and to modify existing command gestures you can remove from the list of clear the list altogether

```cs
ApplicationCommands.Copy.InputGestures.Clear();
ApplicationCommands.Copy.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Q, ModifierKeys.Control));
```